# Ruby optparse: enforce filename in last position

Tags: ruby, optparse

I want to enforce that a filename is always supplied as the **last** argument on top of the optional arguments that are passed in. How can I do this without using a filename switch?

So I want to be able to do something like:

```
./program.rb -o file.xml
```

and **not**

```
./program.rb -o -f file.xml
```

Currently I am doing the following, which works... but I want the banner to be also dynamic and based on the requirement of filename. I have realized this can be achieved using a bit more manual code inside the `OptionParser.new` but looking for more idiomatic way to do this. I don't want to set the banner manually for help.

```
require 'optparse'
require 'ostruct'

options = OpenStruct.new
opt_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on("-o", "--[no-]overwrite", "Overwrite original file") do |o|
    options.overwrite = o
  end
  opts.on("-h", "--help", "Prints this help") do
    puts opts
    exit
  end
end
opt_parser.parse!(ARGV)

xml_file = ARGV.last
```

Comment: When OptionParser is finished parsing and passes into your block, you know you have one parameter, which, by the convention you've set up for your application, is the filename, so do a quick test to see if it exists, and then try opening it for whatever mode you want. It's a contract between you and the user of the software basically, that the filename is last. If you don't trust that contract, then how do you intend to prove that the last parameter isn't yours to use? That it doesn't meet the requirements for a filename? The banner is for you to set to specify that contract.

Comment: In other words, after parsing, the stuff optparse parsed will be removed and ARGV will == ['filename.ext']. Right, @theTinMan?

Comment: IIRC it will be. That's the benefit of OptionParser, it streamlines all that stuff. There are alternatives but they're not part of the standard library.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the expectations are for OptionParser; What about the banner is OP not doing correctly? We need an example of what it's doing wrong and what the desired output would be.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're concerned about, but maybe this will help....

Based on the [minimal example](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#class-OptionParser-label-Minimal+example) in the [OptionParser documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/index.html), I saved this code to disk, then ran it a couple times:

```rb
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

  opts.on("-o", "--[no-]overwrite", "Overwrite original file") do |o|
    options[:overwrite] = o
  end
end.parse!

p options
p ARGV
```

Running it with `ruby test.rb -o foo.bar` resulted in:

```
{:overwrite=>true}
["foo.bar"]
```

so the filename is being left as part of `ARGV`, and doesn't require a flag.

Running `ruby test.rb -h` resulted in:

```
Usage: example.rb [options]
    -o, --[no-]overwrite             Overwrite original file
```

Which was dynamically generated.

If you want the banner to say that the filename is required, simply modify the banner from:

```
opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"
```

to:

```
opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options] filename"
```

and OptionParser will reflect that when using the `-h` flag:

```
Usage: example.rb [options] filename
    -o, --[no-]overwrite             Overwrite original file
```

> I don't want to set the banner manually for help.

But, that's the idiomatic way to reflect that the filename is required. OptionParser has no idea about the significance of trailing parameters and whether they're required or not, it only knows about flags you specify. Anything outside of the flags is optional and you have to code in any further tests:

```
Kernel.abort("Please supply the missing filename.") if ARGV.empty?
```

after the parse block would be my starting point.

[Alternatives](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/CLI_Option_Parsers?display=table&order=score) to OptionParser exist, but whether they are improvements is for you to figure out.